# How to update a entire column using row index and hardcode value in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update the entire **email** column using row **index + email@gmail.com** formate.

This is how the data in my table

| id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | abc@gmail.com |
| 23 | pqr@gmail.com |

This is the output that I want

| id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 1email@gmail.com |
| 23 | 2email@gmail.com |

I tried the below query but it did not give my expected output.

```
   ;with C as
(
  select email,row_number() over(order by id asc) as rowid
  from cus       
)
update C
set email = rowid+'email@gmail.com'
```

This is not only 3 rows there are more than 500 rows in my `cus` table. It is better if someone can give a solution to me without looping. Please help me to create a SQL query for this. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't see how the expected result uses any row index - that looks more like a combination of the ID column and a fixed value to me

Comment: "it did not give a solution for me" - what does that mean?

Comment: that query didn't give the expected output

Comment: You're updating table `C` which is not a _physical_ table, instead it's a common table expression (`cte`).. I suppose you wanted to update table `cus` instead, is it?

Comment: @FanoFN Yep. I want to update the `cus` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're aiming to do:

```
WITH C AS
(
  SELECT email,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id ASC) AS rowid
  FROM cus       
)
UPDATE cus 
 JOIN C
 ON cus.email=C.email
 SET cus.email=CONCAT(rowid,'email@gmail.com');
```

Join the table you want to update (`cus`) with `cte` of `C` then do the update accordingly.

[Here's a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8e4ac063363191eff41d3bb84765e76)

@QisM have raised a concern over this syntax when the `email` is not unique and since OP didn't mention, I agree that this is not the solution if the `email` indeed is not unique. Due to that, I've made a slight modification to the syntax:

```
WITH C AS
(
  SELECT id, email, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id ASC) AS rowid
  FROM cus       
)
UPDATE cus 
 JOIN C
 ON cus.id=C.id AND cus.email=C.email
 SET cus.email=CONCAT(rowid,'email@gmail.com');
```

Now the `cte` is with `id` and the `JOIN C ON ..` condition I've added the checking of matching `id`. Upon testing, [this should fix the issue if e-mail is not unique](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0442e75b98bbdccdef3673ad67590ada).

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work, but i'm sure there is a more elegant solution without the join...

```
SELECT  * FROM cus ;

update
cus  inner join 
(
select  id ,email,row_number() over(order by id asc) as rowid
from cus       
)a
 on a.id = cus.id
set cus.email = concat(a.rowid, a.email)  
;

SELECT  * FROM cus ;
```

complete test

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE cus (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  email TEXT NOT NULL

);

-- insert
INSERT INTO cus VALUES (0021, 'Clark');
INSERT INTO cus VALUES (0402, 'Dave');
INSERT INTO cus VALUES (005, 'Ava' );


SELECT  * FROM cus ;

update
cus  inner join 
(
select  id ,email,row_number() over(order by id asc) as rowid
from cus       
)a
 on a.id = cus.id
set cus.email = concat(a.rowid, a.email)  
;

SELECT  * FROM cus ;
```

Comment: FanoFN  beat me; didn;t see the post

Comment: @FanoFN possibly dangerous joining on the e-mail which might not be Unique?

Comment: Well, OP didn't mention about that but that's a good spot! I'll update my answer accordingly, thanks.